# Valid use of singleton, Objective C

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, singleton

I'm a bit noobish about design patters. I have just started to use singletons, and I was thinking of using one to conveniently store data in a centralized location, but before doing so I read a few posts that seem to be saying this is not correct design (or maybe I am confused), but not clear why. What I want to do is this:

Store several arrays of objects in a centralized place so the objects can be processed for persistence.

If not a singleton is there a better way to do this? If this is bad design would be great to know why.

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad as it is. Based on what you written so far, I can think of multiple arguments for each side. What is it you want to accomplish, specifically.

Comment: http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/ and http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=-FRm3VPhseI and http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/24/how-to-write-3v1l-untestable-code/

Comment: @MikeD specifically I have an app that creates many views and objects. UIViews, ImageViews, UIImages etc. To I need to add all of these views to arrays so I can process them, like for instance if I want to delete all views of a particular type I call on the array, or if I want to persist them I need to enumerate. Also I'd like to store a reference the current "selected" object of each type so that it is accessible to various other vc so that the state of these objects can be changed by various controls.

Comment: It should be recalled that you have a singleton provided by default -- the app delegate.  There is never really a need to have another.  But what most importantly needs to be avoided is an explosion of singletons, with one for each new data structure you add to your app.  This is a sign of a poorly-considered design.

Comment: @Mrwolfy If you are to use a singleton, you should use it only for the model, never for a view or a controller. Views are created dynamically as you bring screens up, and so are the controllers; the model stays the same in your singleton.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight OK, let me see if I understand. If I had an NSMutable array that was created in the singleton, and every time I create a new view(object) I add that view to the array. Does that usage fall under valid design? Thanks.

Comment: @Mrwolfy No, it does not. Storing data that views display in a global mutable array may be OK, but storing view objects themselves is almost definitely wrong: there is no point to access views other than your own, so there should be no justifiable need for a global array of views. Views should not talk to each other directly, only through the model. One view may change a value stored for another view's consumption, and then the other view would be able to display it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many singleton implementations are glorified global variables. While that may seem nice and convenient to somebody who's not written and maintained a lot of code, there are many problems using global variables -- such that they are prohibited by many experienced developers and teams.

> …Store several arrays of objects in a centralized place so the objects can be processed for persistence.

Even one global variable is a pain, but several arrays of them makes a much larger problem.

Ask yourself: Why must all these objects in the arrays always be present and reachable by any part of your program? Only portions of your implementation need this to be visible, and only certain portions at certain times. Why should these arrays of objects always be allocated and active? **Create models and pass them instead, and hold them as ivars where needed.**

Also, if they are persisted, they needn't always be loaded because you can just read/write only what you need *when you need it*.

The use of globals (singleton) are just going to obfuscate the object dependency graph from you (BAD -- maintenance nightmare).

There is no evidence in the OP that your case is atypical. Although it may seem a good idea now, the convenience today often costs a lot in the future.

Much has been written about misuse of global variables and singletons, and the problems they introduce (an ObjC singleton/global is not very different in this regard from an implementation in e.g. C, C++, or Java). Even articles from, say 20 years ago will still have good advice -- the equation is just more complex today.

Answer (score 5):

The usefulness and applicability of the singleton pattern depends a lot on the environment in which it is applied.

The biggest complaint about it is testability of the code that is based on the singleton. Other complaints include potential problems it may present in concurrent environments, and difficulties one may face trying to reclaim the resources owned by the singleton.

However, none of these issues presents a major problem in developing apps for iOS:

- There is usually only one singleton for the model in your application; you can make it swappable to ensure testability, for example by reading the name of the class to instantiate from run-time configuration, or deducing it from the run-time environment.
- Although iOS apps use concurrent constructs, they are for the most part single-threaded.
- iOS apps run until end-user kills them, at which point the operating system reclaims the resources automatically; killing the singleton does not present a particular issue.

Due to these considerations the singleton pattern became a popular implementation technique of iOS apps. As long as you know its shortcomings and are willing to work with them, there is absolutely nothing wrong with using the singleton pattern in your app for iOS.

Comment: Good call. A good example to follow is Apple's own code. They often have a good balance and have made good decisions about when to use and avoid singletons. I think often we get wrapped up in "what ifs". You hit the nail on the head - yes singletons make tests less pure and potentially inaccurate but that is often not a concern for 90% of iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with justin a great deal since the habit is transferrable to other languages. I would just like to add that when considering a singleton ask yourself the question "How will my application benefit by using only one instance of this class?" I'm not the most experienced programmer in the world but I have yet to find any good reason to create a Singleton. Additionally, most frameworks already come with rationally implemented Singletons, such as those that access files/directories (e.g. [NSFileManager defaultManager]). Even then, Apple suggests:

> "If you plan to use a delegate with the file manager to receive
>   notifications about the completion of file-based operations, you
>   should create a new instance of NSFileManager (using the init method)
>   rather than using the shared object."

If you have a single doubt, the class should *not* be a Singleton.